# How to trigger GCP Cloud Function when Dataproc Job state change and read the events

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to figure out the equivalent of AWS lambda EventBridge (CloudWatch Events) where the lambda is triggered when a Glue job state changed. But In GCP I am not found a way how to do it.
If anyone knows please describe or share some resources.

I am using Pub/Sub but it doesn't help out.