# I want to submit a spark job on the dataproc cluster, with custom job id

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using this code to submit a job but it is not mentioned how to pass custom job_id, by default it takes job_uuid as job_id.

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1
job_client = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient(
      client_options={"api_endpoint": "{}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443".format(region)}
  )
job = {
        "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
        "spark_job": {
            "main_class": "de.App",
            "jar_file_uris": [xxxxxx],
            "args": [xxxx],
                        },
                    }
        operation = job_client.submit_job_as_operation(request={"project_id": project_id, "region": region, "job": job})
        response = operation.result()
```

expecting to get custom job_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit the job with a custom `job_id`, you need to modify the job object to include a reference field which will have the `job_id` field you want to use.
For example:

```
job = {
    "reference": {
            "job_id": "custom_job_id"
            },
    "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
    "spark_job": {
            "main_class": "de.App",
            "jar_file_uris": [xxxxxx],
            "args": [xxxx],
                        },
                    }
```

After this modification when you submit the job, it will take the provided `job_id` as `job_id`.

Just make sure that the `job_id` you set must be unique within the project, otherwise it might throw an error.

Comment: Thankyou Saloni Garg, I have One more question pls visit this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067746/how-to-trigger-gcp-cloud-function-when-data-proc-job-state-change-and-read-the-t